# How to define relationship in AgentSpring

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, graph-databases

I am new to AgentSpring and Neo4j, and I just went through a sample. Now I am wondering how to define a relationship between two nodeEntities.

For a node entity, we can use:

```
@RelatedTo(type="TEAMMATE", direction=Direction.BOTH)
public @Fetch Set<Person> teammates;
```

But how can I add more attributes to this teammate relationship? Something like when they begin to be teammates.

I saw there is a class `@RelationshipEntity`, but I do not know how to get `@RelatedTo` and `@RelationshipEntity` connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `@RelatedToVia` instead and use a `@RelationshipEntity` as component type of your set (or your single field type).

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="TEAMMATE")
class Collaboration {
   @StartNode Person p1;
   @EndNode Person p2;
   Date start;
   Date end;
}

@RelatedToVia(type="TEAMMATE", direction=Direction.BOTH)
public Set<Collaboration> teammates;
```

See also the documentation at: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.1.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e1915

Comment: I don't know why when I use collaborations.add(collaboration), and teammates.add(teammate), the time is totally different, adding a relationship with properties is much slower than just building a simple relationship between two persons.